# Making index file, load login screen via AJAX if session doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, session

I have an index file which uses AJAX to load urls.

```
$(function(){
    $('#dashboard').click(function() {
    var req = $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : 'dashboard.php',
        dataType    : 'html'
    });
        req.done(function(data){
            $('#loadcontent').empty().append(data);
        });
    });
    $('#reports, #analytics').click(function() {
        alert('Coming Soon');
    });
    $(#login).load(function() {
    var req = $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : 'loginscreen.php',
        dataType    : 'html'
});
```

On my index page you select overview, and it will load in the middle of screen. This is exactly what I need. However is there a way if a session doesn't exist to load the login screen in the middle of the screen?

At the moment I have tried this

```
<?php 
session_start();
if( ! $_SESSION['loggedIn'] ) {
    // not logged in redirect direct to login page
    echo "<div id='loadcontent' class='col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main'>";  
    header('Location: loginscreen.php');
    echo "</div>";
}
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/config.php')
?>
```

However this will redirect to the page "loginscreen.php" when I want it in the middle of the screen, is there a way to add this to my AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the browser gets the redirect, it redirects the whole window. One thing you could do is this:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if( ! $_SESSION['loggedIn'] ) {
    // not logged in redirect direct to login page
    echo "<div id='loadcontent' class='col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main'>";  
    include "loginpage.php";
    echo "</div>";
    die();
}
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/config.php')
?>
```

Of course, this might hurt your SEO due to duplicate content. To fix this, you might want to just return an empty file if not logged in. If the Javascript detects an empty HTML file (just check to see if there's an important element like the navbar), it will request the login page instead. This will reduce some overhead so it doesn't have to make multiple HTTP requests every time you do something.

Comment: I thought it would be that, now I have the same result. Hmm, at the moment. The index page loads nothing in the middle, until you click a link. Would the url be easier than me explaining? Thank you

Comment: @Runt Are you logged into your site now? If you comment out the if statement does it work? Errors? What link do you click?

Comment: Yes it does, I am now issues with it logging. But this may be a separate issue.

Comment: @Runt create another PHP file just called `test.php` or whatever and try including that to see if that fixes the issue. If so, then your login page needs a little work.

Comment: Fixed the issue with the login, and this now works as expected. Thank you so much!